# How to update array value in MongoDb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

$set is overtiring complete array value how to update it

```
                var obj = // contains some other data to update as well 
                obj.images=images;  //  updating obj with images []
                Units.update({_id: 'id', {$set: obj});
```

finally my  mongo object must be something like this

```
{
"_id" : "ZhBgrNFtr2LRPkQrZ",
"sitouts" : "test",
"interiors" : "test",
"features" : "test",
"keyHolder" : "test",
"images" : [
    "1445481257465-8678-20130520_113154.jpg", ## `updated value ` ##
    "1445481257456-3-20130520_113157.jpg",
    "1445481258058-5771-20130520_113202.jpg",
    "1445481258230-9603-20130521_075648.jpg"
]
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33272682/edit) to your question to show us sample document with the expected result.

Comment: Now what are `obj` and  `images`?

Comment: **obj**  contains details other than images images[] is getting added just before update

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/
$push, $each, $slice. See the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways to update the images array without overwriting it:

**Update a Specific Index**

```
Units.update({_id: id}, {$set: {'images.0': obj.images[0]}})
```

**Append a Single Value**

```
Units.update({_id: id}, {$push: {images: obj.images[0]}})
```

**Append Multiple Values**

```
Units.update({_id: id}, {$push: {images: {$each: obj.images}}})
```